# How can i develop international slack app with webhook?

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

I want to develop notification app for slack. But, we have a international company and some users speak English some users speak Germany. We want to use one channel and i use this json for send a message to slack.

```
{
  "text": "Hello World",
  "username": "User",
  "icon_url": "myiconurl"
}
```

I can send succesfully with this code but i want to send different message for german users and different message for english users.

I am waiting your ideas. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Slack doesn't really have a concept of different content in a channel to users depending on their locale.

You'd either have to post the same message twice, but translated, or send [ephemeral](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) messages to each user in the channel and customise it based on their language preference. You should be aware though that by design, ephemeral messages don't persist in the client, so they'll eventually disappear.